# How do I merge dataframes contained in a meta dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, tibble

My tibble contains multiple dataframes as follows:

| cntry | df |
| --- | --- |
| south_africa | *8 variables* |
| angola | *8 variables* |
| ghana | *8 variables* |

Each sub-dataframe (i.e. one of the variables referred to above) is as follows:

| date | growth | external_financing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | -1 | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | -1 | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | -2 | 1 |

How do I merge all the dataframes to have a column with the country to which that score relates? I would like a result as follows (clearly, some pivoting will also be required):

| date | country | metric | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | south_africa | growth | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | south_africa | growth | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | south_africa | growth | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | south_africa | external_financing | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | south_africa | external_financing | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | south_africa | external_financing | 1 |

And so on...with all the data in this long format.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to `unnest()` your tibble that contains multiple dataframes? To further help you, we might need to have a better idea of how your tibble looks like. Maybe use `dput(yourtibble)` and copy/paste the output in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unnest dataframe within dataframe R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313519/unnest-dataframe-within-dataframe-r)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Unnesting it worked well. I was doing my unnesting later in the process due to some other functions I'm running, but this gets it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `unnest` and `pivot_longer` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  unnest(df) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(cntry, date), 
               names_to = 'metric', values_to = 'score')
```